Cannot delete image out of cloudinary
I want to delete image that I saved in cloudinary. I read docs and they said create an api endpoint to delete the image. I did it and it didnt work. This is my code:
api/admin/cloudinary/removeImage/route.js
import { cloudinary } from "@/backend/utils/cloudinary"

export async function POST(req, res) {
    console.log(' ~ POSTCloud ~ req:', req);
    console.log(' ~ POSTCloud ~ req.body:', req.body);
    try {
        const { public_id } = req.body;
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(public_id);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Image deleted successfully from Cloudinary' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(' ~ POST ~ error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong!' });
    }
}

and this is frontend code:
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Plus, Trash } from "lucide-react"
import Image from "next/image"
import axios from "axios"
import { CldUploadWidget } from 'next-cloudinary'

const ImageUpload = ({ onChange, onRemove, value }) => {
    const onUpload = (result) => {
        onChange(result.info.secure_url)
    }

    const removeFromCloudinary = async (publicId) => {
        console.log(' ~ removeFromCloudinary ~ TypeOfpublicId:', typeof publicId)
        try {
            console.log(' ~ removeFromCloudinary ~ publicId:', publicId)
            const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/admin/cloudinary/removeImage`, { public_id: publicId })
            console.log('Image removed from Cloudinary')
            console.log(' ~ removeFromCloudinary ~ response:', response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error removing image from Cloudinary:', error)
        }
    }

    const handleRemove = async (url) => {
        try {
            const publicId = url.split('/').pop().replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
            console.log('Public ID:', publicId);
            await removeFromCloudinary(publicId);
            onRemove(url);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error removing image:', error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <div className="mb-4 flex flex-wrap items-center gap-4">
                {value.map((url) => (
                    <div key={url} className="relative w-[200px] h-[200px]">
                        <div className="absolute top-0 right-4 z-10">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                onClick={() => handleRemove(url)}
                                className="bg-red-500 p-2 rounded-md text-white"
                            >
                                <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <Image src={url} alt="collection" className="object-cover rounded-lg" fill />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            <CldUploadWidget uploadPreset="ml_default" onUpload={onUpload}>
                {({ open }) => {
                    return (
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => open()} className="bg-gray-600 text-white flex items-center gap-1 p-3 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-700">
                            <Plus className="h-6 w-6 mr-2" />
                            <p>Upload Image</p>
                        </button>
                    )
                }}
            </CldUploadWidget>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImageUpload

I log the req.body in API and I received: ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
and log of req like
 ~ POSTCloud ~ req: NextRequest [Request] {
  [Symbol(realm)]: {
    settingsObject: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] }
  },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    method: 'POST',
    localURLsOnly: false,
    unsafeRequest: false,
    body: { stream: undefined, source: null, length: null },
    client: { baseUrl: undefined, origin: [Getter], policyContainer: [Object] },
    reservedClient: null,
    replacesClientId: '',
    window: 'client',
    keepalive: false,
    serviceWorkers: 'all',
    initiator: '',
    destination: '',
    priority: null,
    origin: 'client',
    policyContainer: 'client',
    referrer: 'client',
    referrerPolicy: '',
    mode: 'cors',
    useCORSPreflightFlag: true,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    useCredentials: false,
    cache: 'default',
    redirect: 'follow',
    integrity: '',
    cryptoGraphicsNonceMetadata: '',
    parserMetadata: '',
    reloadNavigation: false,
    historyNavigation: false,
    userActivation: false,
    taintedOrigin: false,
    redirectCount: 0,
    responseTainting: 'basic',
    preventNoCacheCacheControlHeaderModification: false,
    done: false,
    timingAllowFailed: false,
    headersList: _HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [Array]
    },
    urlList: [ URL {} ],
    url: URL {
      href: 'http://localhost:3000/api/admin/cloudinary/removeImage',
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      protocol: 'http:',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: '3000',
      pathname: '/api/admin/cloudinary/removeImage',
      search: '',
      searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
      hash: ''
    }
  },
  [Symbol(signal)]: AbortSignal { aborted: false },
  [Symbol(abortController)]: AbortController { signal: AbortSignal { aborted: false } },
  [Symbol(headers)]: _HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(21) {
      'accept' => [Object],
      'accept-encoding' => [Object],
      'accept-language' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'cookie' => [Object],
      'host' => [Object],
      'origin' => [Object],
      'referer' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile' => [Object],
      'sec-ch-ua-platform' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-dest' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-mode' => [Object],
      'sec-fetch-site' => [Object],
      'user-agent' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-for' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-host' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-port' => [Object],
      'x-forwarded-proto' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: [
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array],
      [Array], [Array], [Array]
    ]
  },
  [Symbol(internal request)]: {
    cookies: RequestCookies { _parsed: [Map], _headers: [_HeadersList] },
    geo: {},
    ip: undefined,
    nextUrl: NextURL { [Symbol(NextURLInternal)]: [Object] },
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/admin/cloudinary/removeImage'
  }
}


do you have the response you received from Cloudinary? It looks like request is not reaching Cloudinary. More on destroy here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy
